# How to get only 30 seconds of a song using python

Tags: python

I want when i play a song in python it only plays the first 30 seconds of a song only no matter the length of it. I want this to be done without creating a new mp3 file. I have pydub but what is actually doing is creating a new file with 30 seconds cut which is taking too long to load on my Django page.

```
   startMin = 9
   startSec = 50

   endMin = 13
   endSec = 30

   # Time to miliseconds
   startTime = startMin*60*1000+startSec*1000
   endTime = endMin*60*1000+endSec*1000

   # Opening file and extracting segment
   song = AudioSegment.from_mp3( item_media.file.path )
   extract = song[startTime:endTime]

   extract.export( 'Zoo'+'-extract.mp3', format="mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want this to be done without creating a new mp3 file.

Unless you're willing for the client to have the full file, and then manipulate e.g. an `<audio>` element to only play a part of it, that's not easily possible. (Technically, for an MP3 file, you *might* be able to seek the MP3 frame for a given time offset, and write MP3 frames until you've found the end offset, and browsers *should* be able to play a file mangled like that, but it's probably not worth the technical effort.)

If the issue is only that it takes too long for the extraction, only do it once for a given file and cache the result:

```
import os
import tempfile
import hashlib


def get_extract_mp3(original_path, startMin, startSec, endMin, endSec):
    # Time to miliseconds
    startTime = int(startMin * 60 * 1000 + startSec * 1000)
    endTime = int(endMin * 60 * 1000 + endSec * 1000)

    original_path_hash = hashlib.sha256(original_path.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
    cache_file = os.path.join(
        tempfile.gettempdir(), f"extract-{original_path_hash}-{startTime}-{endTime}.mp3"
    )
    if not os.path.isfile(cache_file):  # No cache file yet
        # Opening file and extracting segment
        song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(original_path)
        extract = song[startTime:endTime]

        # Write the extract to a temporary file...
        tmp_cache_file = cache_file + ".tmp"
        extract.export(tmp_cache_file, format="mp3")
        # ... and replace it into place
        os.replace(tmp_cache_file, cache_file)

    return cache_file
```

...

```
def my_view(...):
   extract_path = get_extract_mp3(item_media.file.path, 9, 50, 13, 50)
   return FileResponse(open(extract_path, 'rb'))
```

This way only the first client to request an extract for a given file and a given time will have to wait for it to happen.

You may wish to put the cache files somewhere else than `gettempdir()`, maybe a subdirectory thereof, and will want to make sure to clean it every once in a while too (e.g. delete the oldest files).

Comment: I don't know where the problem is but the extracted files are all showing 255 bits size.

Comment: I don't know where the problem is either. Are the cache files the wrong size, or the result you get in the browser truncated? Did you take a look at the contents of the files?

Comment: Yes i did i have tried two files with more than 2MB but still doing the same

Comment: Again: what is 255 bits (I presume you mean bytes)? The response you get from the view? Or the `extract-...mp3` files in the temporary directory?

Comment: So any solution?

Comment: Did you read my last comment? I can't help you find a solution if we don't know where the fault occurs.

Comment: Yes i meant bytes